# How can someone don't put 2 times an ip

Tags: regex

This is my regex

```
/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/
```

but someone was able to do something like this

**1.1.1.1-1.1.1.1**

How can I forgit that I just want to have 1 ip not 2

Comment: You need `$` at the end to force the RegEx to match the entire string (rather than just a prefix of the string, which you already enforce using `^`)

Comment: @Luatic can  u write it as an answer so I can validate it ?

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$` at the end to force the RegEx to match the entire string (rather than just a prefix of the string, which you already enforce using `^`).